# Stream activation for beep

Tags: android, audio

I want to make a beep on errors.

I found:

```
ToneGenerator tone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 50);
```

with:

```
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ABBR_ALERT);
```

and I tried various other streams.

But I don't hear nothing.

Do I have to set permissions?
And if so, which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

With
STREAM_ALARM
and
TONE_PROP_BEEP